# Angular unit test cannot see .glsl files

Tags: angular, webpack, ionic3, angular5

I am using `ng test` command in my Angular 5 application.
When I run tests it informs me that

```
ERROR in ./src/vr.frag.glsl
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| @nomangle NAME_CHANGED_STH NAME_CHANGED_STH NAME_CHANGED_STH
| 
| @include "@changed/shaders/common.glsl"
```

How can I set this preloader on karma.conf.js?